# Why can one assume - without loss of generality - that $c_n = 1$ when proving the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

So I'm looking at Rudin's principles of mathematical analysis theorem 8.8 (fundamental theorem of algebra):

> Suppose $c_1, ..., c_n$ are complex numbers, $n\geq1,\;a_n\neq0$, $$P(z) = \sum_0^na_kz^k.$$ Then $P(z) = 0$ for some complex $z$.

The proof starts with the sentence:

> Without loss of generality, assume $a_n =1$.

And I'm not entirely sure why this is even allowed. It would be great if someone could explain this to me?

Comment: If it is not $1$, we can divide it so that it becomes $1$.

Comment: Also, it's the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$P(z) = 0$ if and only if $\frac{1}{a_n}P(z)=0$ so it doesn't matter.  The result of this converts the coefficient of $z^n$ to $1$.

Comment: beat me to it..

Comment: Well I'm sitting in office hours now so I'm super bored (but I shouldn't be).

Comment: Hah. When I was a TA in grad school I preferred not having anyone showing up to complain about a point lost here or there :p